# Docker' Union FS: Reordering of layers / commands

Tags: docker

For example I have two images I want to install, both are from the same base image (e.g. `ubuntu`) but they install dependencies in different order (e.g. the first image installs `java` first and then `python`, the second one installs `python` and then `java`).

- Will be anything except `ubuntu` image reused or it will store dependencies twice, i.e. storing the same big files for this dependencies twice in its union FS?
- If no, then if these dependencies do not affect the same files / environmental variables thus forming equal snapshot of file system regardless of the order of commands, will the layer be reused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion for sharing layers is running the exact same command on the exact same base layer.  So in the cases you describe, there will not be layer sharing (other than the base `ubuntu` layers).

If you really routinely have the need for multiple language runtimes in the same image, you can create your own base layer that’s Ubuntu and Java and Python all together.  Have your CI system build that and push it to some respository, and then have your multi-language application images be built `FROM` that layer.  This will simplify your Dockerfiles and somewhat improve disk utilization.

Comment: But if I install, for example, an image that uses only Java, then Java will be stored twice: in this layer with only Java and in the layer with Python and Java, am I correct? I've asked if I missed something in avoiding such a wasting of memory)

Comment: If you have an image with (Ubuntu+Java), and install Python on top of that, you will get a layer that’s in effect just (+Python) and wind up with an image with both language runtimes.  The layers just store deltas on top of the underlying images.